# How to check if an input element is hidden?

Tags: jquery

How can you check if an input element is hidden?

Comment: Do you mean `hidden` as in `type="hidden"` or `hidden` as in `display: none`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Hidden as `type="hidden"`

```
$("#myInputElement").attr('type') == 'hidden'
```

Hidden as `display: none`

```
$("#myInputElement").is(":hidden")
```

Answer (score 17):

[nickf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9021/nickf) is right, but that would have the same effect on an input that is hidden by style (`style="display:none;"`) or by it's `type` attribute (`type="hidden"`).
Consider the following html :

```
<input id="first" type="hidden" />
<input id="second" type="text" style="display:none;"/>
```

Both of the above inputs have the `:hidden` pseudoclass, but only one of them has the `hidden` type. Assuming that this is what you were looking for (because inputs are the only elements that can have a hidden type and you wanted to check if an **input element** is hidden, not just any other element), the right answer to you r question is to check the element's type attribute:

```
document.getElementById('first').getAttribute('type') == 'hidden';// true
// although this input is also hidden, it wouldn't pass the check
document.getElementById('second').getAttribute('type') == 'hidden';// false
```

and , of course, the jquery way :

```
$('#first').attr('type') == 'hidden';// true
$('#second').attr('type') == 'hidden';// false
```

If you only were interested in the plain visibility property, then the jquery pseudoclass does the trick :

```
$('#first').is(':hidden');
// or another way
$('#first:hidden').length != 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

HTMLElement.hidden should return true if it owns the hidden attribute.

```
document.querySelector('h1').hidden === true
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method of the Element interface returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be `null` or `""` (the empty string);

for a hidden element, you can check the `type` attribute of element.

```
$('#myElement').getAttribute('type')=='hidden'
```