# How to show message in hidden field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an input field that stores vales for checking a condition.I changed this to hidden: if the condition is false I need to show a message.

If the field is hidden,the message is not shown.

**html**

```
 <input type="hidden" id="year1_req_fund_hidden" name="year1_req_fund_hidden">
```

**jquery**

```
#wizard5').validate(
{
  rules: {

       year1_req_fund_hidden:{
                    //required:true,
                     number:true,
                     validate_check: [$('#year1_grand_amt').val(),'1'],
                    },
          }, 
 });


 $.validator.addMethod("validate_check",
  function(value, element, params) {
  if(params[0]!=''){
  if(value == params[0]) {
     return true;
     }
   }
  },
 $.format("The total amount requested does not match with grant amount {0} requested in Q1.11 in year {1} .")

  );
```

Comment: This will give you some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966221/how-to-check-if-an-input-element-is-hidden

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#wizard5').validate({
   ignore:'', // or ignore: []
   rules: {

         year1_req_fund_hidden:{
                //required:true,
                 number:true,
                 validate_check: [$('#year1_grand_amt').val(),'1'],
           },
     }, 
 });
```

Your code should be as per above

It will work for you. By default, jQuery Validation ignores hidden fields.
http://prntscr.com/g0urkk

Comment: its not woking bro

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/
Please refer to this link. Might be your validate_check function is not working

Answer (score 1):

This way can solve your problem...!

```js
if (!$('input').attr('id') == null) {
    //check your condition according to you
    //your action here
} else {
    //show your message in .hidden div
    $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow').html('Message');
}
```

```css
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="year1_req_fund_hidden" name="year1_req_fund_hidden">
<!-- Place below div where you want to show your message -->
<div class="hidden"></div>
```